# virtual hosts WAMP server

Tags: apache, wamp

I am trying to setup virtual wamp localhost.

Localhost
root folder: c:\wamp\www

mysite.local
root folder: c:\wamp\site2

Steps of every kind is already taken: removing # from file "httpd.conf"

```
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

addition in  httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
ServerName localhost
ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common 
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/site2"
ServerName mysite.local
<directory "c:/wamp/site2">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

addition in hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1    mysite.local
```

problem is, in either case i get to www root folder through localhost or mysite.local. ANy solution?

Comment: Are you restarting Apache after you change any httpd configuration files?

Comment: yup. even restarting complete windows :)

Comment: Are you certain you are editing the httpd.conf that is actually in use?

Comment: Wamp>bin>apache>apache 2.4.9>conf> httpd.conf. YES, i am editing it.

Comment: All I can tell you is the setup you have described works perfectly on my machine. Your virtual host setup is fine and your hosts file is fine. Check for .htaccess files that redirect in c:\wamp\site2. Try breaking the virtual hosts config file with some clearly wrong syntax, make sure Apache actually won't start when it is broken - this is the best way to confirm you have the right file. Make sure there are no funny rules in the main httpd.conf about the document root.

Answer (score 0):

```
//httpd.conf

>LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
```

Delete the comment icon (#), it may help.

Answer (score 0):

Now use [WAMP Latest Version 3](http://www.wampserver.com/en/#wampserver-64-bits-php-5-6-25-php-7) And create Virtual Host from Localhost web page directly. After Register the Virtual Host just restrat the WAMP server.